# AWK Multilines into Single line record

Tags: awk

The data below has to be converted into string

```
01 |
0101001001 |
DD-01-001-001-001/57 |
1 |
Vijay Raghavan |
 |
3096 |
Govind Industries |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
  </EmployeeData>
```

with the code below (in a .awk file) :

```
#BEGIN {FS ="\n" ; RS="[</EmployeeData>]"}
#{
#for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
#print $i","
#}
```

There is no output. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of potential problems. First, the value of `RS` that was used did not match the text that it was intended to match (which was why there was no output). Second, `print` automatically puts a newline at the end of the text that it prints, so the output would be on multiple lines anyway.

The following script solves both problems:

```
BEGIN {FS ="\n" ; RS="</EmployeeData>"}
{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "%s,",$i;
    printf "\n";
}
```

Comment: It's giving an "invalid char' error. *I am working in Windows). Also, there are leading spaces in the "EmployeeData" line...

Comment: This is not the way to do this job in awk. See either of the other answers posted (by Kent & Jotne & myself) for a better starting point. Note that any of the solutions that set RS to more than 1 char are GNU-awk-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `awk`

```
awk -F"\n" -v RS="</EmployeeData>" '{$1=$1}1' file
01 | 0101001001 | DD-01-001-001-001/57 | 1 | Vijay Raghavan |  | 3096 | Govind Industries |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
```

If you like `,` as separator do:

```
awk -F"\n" -v RS="</EmployeeData>" '{$1=$1;gsub(/ \| /,",")}1' file
01,0101001001,DD-01-001-001-001/57,1,Vijay Raghavan,,3096,Govind Industries,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk -v RS="" '{$1=$1}7'  file
```

the above line will merge all lines into one, including the `</EmployeeData>`

Answer (score 0):

`#` is the awk comment-start character. Every line in your posted .awk file is commented out, hence no output. Also, `RS="[</EmployeeData>]"` does not set RS to the string `</EmployeeData>` as I suspect was desired, it sets it to any of the characters in the list `< / E m p l o y e D a t` courtesy of the character-list delimiters `[]`.

I think this is probably what you really are looking for (uses GNU awk for multi-char RS):

```
$ cat file
01 |
0101001001 |
DD-01-001-001-001/57 |
1 |
Vijay Raghavan |
 |
3096 |
Govind Industries |
 |
 |
  </EmployeeData>
02 |
0202002002 |
DD-01-001-001-001/57 |
1 |
Bob Shmobswort |
 |
1234 |
Some Other Places |
 |
 |
  </EmployeeData>
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{FS="[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*"; OFS=","; RS="</EmployeeData>[[:space:]]*"}
{ $1=$1; print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
01,0101001001,DD-01-001-001-001/57,1,Vijay Raghavan,,3096,Govind Industries,,,
02,0202002002,DD-01-001-001-001/57,1,Bob Shmobswort,,1234,Some Other Places,,,
```